# Rstudio table of means from a large dataset

Tags: rstudio, mean

I am working with a large dataset in Rstudio, with 21 columns of data each filled with information from many time points (roughly 92 rows). I can work out the mean for each column individually but am really struggling to calculate all the means at once, thus producing a table of 21 mean results. Is there a way of doing this? I'm wondering if part of the problem is that my columns have a alpha-numeric title?

(Apologies if it's really easy, I just don't seem to be getting anywhere with it).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If your data frame is named `df`, you can use

```
colMeans(df)
```

You can easily store that to a dataframe itself as

```
means_df <- data.frame(colMeans(df))
```

Comment: Thanks, I think that the big problem I had was that some of my data were factors. Now managed to get the means though so thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways. If you like to do it by using base R, use this

```
apply(df,2,mean)
```

If you like to do it by using `dplyr` package, try this

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% summarize_each(funs(mean))
```

If you like to use `data.table` package, then it will be

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)
dt[, lapply(.SD, mean)]
```

**Data**

```
df <- data.frame(A=rnorm(100),B=runif(100),C=1:100)
```

Comment: Thanks, I think that the big problem I had was that some of my data were factors. Now managed to get the means though so thank you.